# If there are dates in these rows show the earliest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to get a return date which is the most recent date from three columns? I currently have this:

[image: Current Data Example]

Sometimes an item is just delivered, sometimes its attempted to be delivered then eventually picked up, and sometimes it is attempted to be delivered and then delivered. I would like the most recent date out of the three columns to be returned this below, and the activity:

[image: Desired Data Example]

If there's no date yet I'd like to to return as blank

Comment: Please don't add data as an image, add data as text as per SO guidelines

Comment: Would it make sense that if there is a Delivered date that would be the most recent? The same should be true for AttemptedDelivery? If those are true this becomes trivial using coalesce. And it has to be said that you can't have a "blank" when dealing with dates. In those cases you want NULL. But I have a feeling from your posted sample images that you are not using the date datatype.

Comment: If you're in Azure, use [`GREATEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If you're using on premises, a Search of how to achieve the same functionality in your favourite search engine will certainly give you plenty of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without some sample data and desired output but a guess would be something like:

```
SELECT NewColumn FROM
(
  SELECT [Attempted Delivery] as NewColumn FROM SomeTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [Picked-up] as NewColumn FROM SomeTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [Delivered] as NewColumn FROM SomeTable
) A
Group by NewColumn
ORDER BY NewColumn DESC
```